# Count specific value across multiple columns and divide total values per column with excluding '0'

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working data set consisting of multiple columns with 0,1,2 value. I am trying to compute the number of times either 1 or 2 occurrences across multiple columns and finally would like to divide the total number of times for both 1 and 2.

Below is the data subset:

input

[image]

expected result

[image]

sorry for inconvenience! as i was new to this

```
  df <- structure(list(Pool = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), a = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), b = c(2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), c = c(0L,0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
    0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), d = c(0L,0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 
    2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), e = c(2L,2L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L), f = c(2L,2L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L), g = c(2L,1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), h =c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L)),row.names = c(NA,15L), class = "data.frame")
```

If anyone could help for solution, Thank you for your time

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We cannot read data into R from images. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(input)`.

Comment: #neilfws, how do I attach txt format? could you please suggest me?

Comment: You could copy/paste the output of `dput(input)` to your question, so that we can use your data.

Comment: Thank you so much #Darren Tsai, i tried this time. But i dont have 'L' after value i am not sure how it appeared in dput output

Comment: `L` means integer values. You can run `class(1)` and `class(1L)` to see the difference. In addition, the dput output is inconsistent with the data in the image. You should check before you post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ mean(.x[.x != 0] == 2)))
```

Comment: this answer is straight as an arrow! awesome # Darren Tsai.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this base R approach, though I am sure there are more elegant solutions. From your desired output, it looks like you want to calculate the proportion of 2's out of all 1's and 2's.

#### Data

Reproducible example data, which from your screenshot seems to be heavily favored for a value of 2

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:3, each = 5),
                 matrix(sample(0:2, 120, replace = TRUE, prob = c(20/120, 8/120, 92/120)), ncol = 8))
colnames(df)[-1] <- letters[1:8]colnames(df)[-1] <- letters[1:8]

head(df, 5)
#   ID a b c d e f g h
# 1  1 2 0 1 2 2 2 2 0
# 2  1 0 2 0 2 2 2 2 0
# 3  1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
# 4  1 0 2 0 2 2 2 2 2
# 5  1 1 1 2 0 0 2 2 2
```

Note the numbers differ from your question since the data were provided as a screenshot and this code created data at random.

#### Code

Splits the data frame by group then applies a function to tabulate and divide the data (`a`) then recombine everything into a final data frame (`b`). Also checks to see if there are any values of 2 at all, else returns `NA`.

```
a <- lapply(split(df[, -1], df$ID), function(x)
  lapply(x, function(y) {
    t <- data.frame(table(y))
    if (any(t$y == 2)) {
      round(t[t$y == 2, "Freq"] / sum(t[t$y %in% 1:2, "Freq"]), 1)
    }
    else {
      NA
    }
  }))

b <- data.frame(ID = unique(df$ID), do.call(rbind, a))
```

#### Output:

```
# > b
#   ID    a    b    c d e    f   g   h
# 1  1 0.67 0.75 0.67 1 1    1   1   1
# 2  2    1 0.75    1 1 1    1   1 0.6
# 3  3  0.8    1    1 1 1 0.67 0.8 0.8
```

Comment: Thank you so much for #jpsmith, your wonderful help, two things I would like to explore in the above code. what is x and y functions are doing? my output came as 'dbl' instead of integer, i got error! while I convert to integer (as.integer (b)) [Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'integer']